Rownum issue in Oracle
There is a select query which gives 4.8 Mn records.
When I am trying to get the output for first Million rows in the following way, it's working fine:
Select * from
(
Source Query
)
Where rownum <1000000
But when I try to do the same to get the records from 10 Million till 20 Million by changing the above where clause, it's giving 0 rows as output.
Whereas the total count from select query is 4.8 Mn...
Why is it happening?
Not getting any row as output from above logic

where's the other query???

You cannot filter on WHERE ROWNUM >= 100000 because the first row is given ROWNUM of 1 then the WHERE filter is applied and it doesn't match so the next row is then given a ROWNUM of 1 as well, since no previous rows were matched by the filter, and repeat and then all the rows will be discarded. You are looking for something like SELECT * FROM (SELECT s.*, ROWNUM rn FROM ( Source Query ) s WHERE rownum < 2000000) WHERE rn >= 1000000 (where you filter on the upper bound and then number the rows and filter the numbered rows on the lower bound).

Alternatively, from Oracle 12, you can use SELECT * FROM ( Source Query ) ORDER BY something OFFSET 1000000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1000000 ROWS ONLY

The key thing to understand here is that rownum is assigned only to the result set. It is not a property of the data in the table. If you don't sort your data in some way that gives rownum meaning your result set will essentially be random, not paginated as you seem to be trying to do.
